# Django Upon click, URL changes, but page is not loaded

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm new to Django and Python. In my current project, a new home page was created.  I was assigned to work on login & signup page that are part of the home page links.  My login and signup pages are ready working fine when typing their respective URLs directly in the address bar; but when login/signup is connected to an anchor tag, only the URL in the address bar changes and the control remains in home page itself.  I had to press enter on address bar to load the login/signup pages.

Login/Signup are the first two links tried in this home page, there is no other working link in this page that I could refer for this issue's solution.  This is the case for any links introduced in the home page.

When trying debug option in VS, with breakpoint in urls.py file, one breakpoint in the home page class, it was identified that upon  click, those breakpoints did not hit (ie) there was no function call upon those clicks.

I tried the following as suggested in few related SO questions.

1. Confirmed that there is no duplicate function names in the views.py file
2. Checked the pattern of URL.py file values

**myproject/myproject/urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = [   
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view() ,name="login"),
    url(r'register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(), name="register"),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls', namespace="myapp")),  
  ]
```

**myproject/myapp/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'getl/$', views.GetLView.as_view(), name="get l"),
    url(r'gett/$', views.GetTView.as_view(), name="get t"),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<user>\w+)/$', views.AccountActivationView.as_view(), name="account activation"),
    url(r'^(?P<app>\w+)/$', views.MyAppView.as_view(), name="Myapp"),
    url(r'^$', views.MyView.as_view(), name="my home"),
]
```

**myproject/templates/home.html**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">SIGN IN</a>
```

Any help to identify the issue would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: It might be javascript issue. check it once.

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta, can you please be specific on what should be checked in JS?

Comment: jquery or javascript events are might be blocking the default behaviour of  anchor tag.

Comment: You didn't show the rest of your URLs. As is suggested from the one you did show, you haven't terminated your regex patterns.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, issue exists even with url r'^login/$'.

Comment: Yes because the error is in *one of your other URLs*, which you didn't show, also not being terminated.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, if there is error in other URLs, how does the same url when entered in address bar directly, loads the login/signup page? Please advise

Comment: Because the non-terminated regex is matching the empty string, or a prefix for login, or something. Show the URLs and we'll be able to tell you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, now I have updated the question with entire urls.py code.